# Import multiple urls into a single viewable property in Hubspot sales

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-api, hubspot-cms

I would like to import multiple vacancy urls when importing a company in Hubspot.

So when importing a new company using an Excel, I naturally import a lot of properties. Most of them are singular, like "Organizationame". I also have couple of urls, pointing to certain vacancys online. This are just regular public urls. Is there a way I can get these nicely under eachother, so a viewer can click on them?